# Getting module name with ast

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

How to get a python module name using ast? I tried the following to get the Module Node, but looks like it does not have the name information:

```
class v(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Module(self, node):
        print "Module : %s" % node

v().visit_Module(ast.parse(f.read(), filename))
```

I basically need the actual module name (If it is inside a package then the complete one like a.b.module).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIU, this information doesn't exist in `ast`. More formally, the abstract grammar for Module in Python is:

```
mod = Module(stmt* body)
    | Interactive(stmt* body)
    | Expression(expr body)

    -- not really an actual node but useful in Jython's typesystem.
    | Suite(stmt* body)
```

So as you can see a `Module` just has a body which is a list of statement nodes. There's no name.

Do note that you pass `f.read()` to the visitor. That returns the contents of the file, without actually knowing or caring how that file is named - where can you take the module name from it?

From executing Python code, you can use `__name__` and `__package__` from inside Python code.